# How can I create a valid Codepipeline Arn using CDK(python) with Arn class?

Tags: aws-cdk

Using this [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/discussions/21559) post, I crafted a Python snippet:

```py
    vm_pipeline_qa = Stack.of(self).format_arn(
                region="us-east-1",
                service="codepipeline",
                resource="pipeline",
                account="111122223333",
                resource_name="vm_pipeline_qa"
            )
```

### Current Behavior

The above code snippet creates the following codepipeline Arn:

`arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:111122223333:pipeline/vm_pipeline-`

### Expected Behavior

A valid codepipeline Arn using Codepipeline console would resemble the following:

`arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-1:111122223333:vm_pipeline-`

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the expected output:

```py
vm_pipeline_qa = Stack.of(self).format_arn(
            account="111122223333",
            region="us-east-1",
            service="codepipeline",
            resource="vm_pipeline_qa",                  # <- put the resource name into the resource slot
            arn_format=cdk.ArnFormat.NO_RESOURCE_NAME,  # <- omit the resource name slot
        )
```

Tip:  `account` and `region` are inherited from `Stack.of(self)` by default.